# Can I remote into my machine from a VM that's running on my machine?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, remote-access, remote

What would happen if I started a VM on my machine and remoted into my machine from the VM? I haven't tried this, because I'm scared of breaking the universe.

Comment: It's possible but depends on the network settings in the virtualization software.

Comment: Nothing. It would be like using TeamViewer to connected to a system, that is connected to you, by TeamViewer.

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Comment: Using Remote Desktop Connection, the moment I connected to my machine, it locked my computer, and after logging back in, it display an error message "Your Remote Desktop Services session has ended. Another user connected to the remote computer, so your connection was lost. Try connecting again, or contact your network administrator or technical support group."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your host OS is and how it's configured to handle remote sessions.  You didn't mention whether your host is Windows or Linux, but assuming it's Windows, you could end up locking the console.  You could test this by setting up a second guest, and then remoting to *that*, and observing what happens to it.  On some versions of Windows, if you're logged in locally, and then remote to the same PC from somewhere else (via RDP), the local session will go to the "lock screen" and anything running will transfer to the remote session.  You can transfer it back by just logging in locally again, which will kill the remote session.  However, some other versions (mostly the Server versions) have a separate session for RDP which is independent of the local session.

It just dawned on me that you could be talking about a different kind of remote access, in which you interact directly with the console (for example, VNC).  In that case you'd probably get the same effect as a closed-circuit camera pointed at the monitor that it's sending its output to - an infinite nesting of displays inside displays.  That could get interesting.

Comment: "local session will go to the "lock screen" and anything running will transfer to the remote session. You can transfer it back by just logging in locally again, which will kill the remote session." - this is exactly what happened to me.

Comment: If you're interested, there's a way to configure Windows 7 to allow multiple remote sessions.  See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/655ed2a6-e9fc-486c-bcbe-02fe3f59c206/multiple-rdp-sessions-for-windows-7?forum=w7itprogeneral.  I **think** this would also allow one remote session and one local session.

Answer (score 0):

It would work fine.  The whole idea of a VM is that it appears seperate to the host system - so from a conceptual point of view, it would be like connecting to to a seperate system (although it happens to be on the same hardware)

Comment: But the VM's going to have to have access to ports, which the host system also needs. Will the VM have a separate MAC?